# How do I keep a node centered while animating scale in Godot?

Tags: animation, gui, transformation, godot

When scale is modulated, the item scales from the top-left corner.  I tried changing anchors preset to "center" but it still scaled from the top-left corner.  How do I make it scale from center?

[image: Layout settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are scaling with `scale`, what you need to do is set the `pivot_offset` to the center of the `Control`, i.e. to half of `size` (which is the size of the `Control` before scaling).

In general the `Control` will scale *and rotate* keeping the point specified by `pivot_offset` in place. So when the `pivot_offset` is `Vector2(0, 0)` (which is the default) `scale` *and `rotation`* will keep the top left corner in place.

Thus - to reiterate - change `pivot_offset` to the center *or whatever position you want to keep fixed during scaling and rotation*.

Comment: So if I change size, I'll have to change pivot_offset every-time?

Comment: @SephReed If you change the `size`? yes. If you change the `scale` of the `Control`? no.